# What does the word skull mean in that context

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I was reading [an article](http://www.aipsmedia.com/2016/09/01/19440/rio-2016-zimbabwe-sports-journalists-olympic-games-arrest-allegations) about the alleged arrest of all Zimbabwean athletes on their arrival to home and this sentence, the legend below the picture of the team, perplexed me.

> Zimbabwe's Olympic delegation in Rio included 31 athletes, with 5th place obtain in rowing, women's skull the best result

What does the word "skull" mean here? It might be an error, I think, so what is supposed to be in its place then?

I looks like it might be a verb, but it can't because of the word "women's" (I do not know the correct linguistic term for it) indicating a possession, it is like an adjective.

And if "skull" here is a noun, than I cannot figure out its meaning. The head bone seems to have no sense here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about a misspelled word. The OP has the answer and there is no further value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a misspelling of ***sculls***:

> a race between boats in which each participant uses a pair of oars.

<sup>New Oxford American Dictionary</sup>

> Zimbabwe has qualified one boat each in both the men's and women's
>   single sculls for the Games at the 2015 African Continental
>   Qualification Regatta in Tunis, Tunisia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zimbabwe_at_the_2016_Summer_Olympics#Rowing

---

Note that the caption appears to be written by someone not well-versed in English: "*5th place obtain in rowing*" should be "*5th place **obtained** in rowing*".